# Elastic search not accessible remotely

Tags: elasticsearch, remote-access

I am trying to access Elastic Search remotely, but getting connection error.

When I curl localhost:9200 in the remote server, I get the desired output. But remotely server_address:9200 is not accessible.

Any suggestions?

Comment: In the config file (probably `elasticsearch.yml`), has the `network.bind_host` property been set to anything?

Comment: Do you add any permission(Security) in your Elastic search.

Answer (score 1):

In elasticsearch.yml file modify/add network.host setting as below.

```
network.host: 0.0.0.0
```

and then restart your elasticsearch server.

Answer (score 0):

Change (/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml)network_host IP to your server private IP address.Then the ES can be access with same network range.

```
network.host: "192.168.xx.xx"
http.port: 9200
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit your `elasticsearch.yml` file.

```
network.host: server_ip
http.port: 9200
transport.tcp.port: 9300
```